# Best 2D c++ API?

Tags: c++, api, 2d

I am looking for a good 2D C++ API. I have looked into SDL, but I was hoping for something a little more high level like pygame or cocoa except for C++. The only other thing is that it must have Linux support. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for line drawing/vectorization or sprites and game programming, as you can see by the answers those are two separate areas

Comment: and by which criteria do you determine "best-ness"?

Comment: I think pygame uses SDL in it, I say try out SDL again, and it does have linux support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Allegro](http://alleg.sourceforge.net). Particularly the Allegro 5 release. Its got support for OpenGL/DirectX and a lot of "addons" like zip reading functionality, loading all kinds of images, advanced sound support, etc. The binaries are also available [here](http://www.allegro.cc/files/).

Its a little bit more "high level" than SDL, but not by much. Check it out and decide for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Theres not such a thing, like the "best 2D C++ API". Anyway, have a look at openFrameworks, if you prefer a high level library.

http://www.openframeworks.cc/

It uses OpenGL and is also available for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [game engine database](http://gpwiki.org/index.php/Game_Engines), see which ones support 2D graphics operations (graphics column). Another useful resource is DevMaster.net's 3D engine list, try doing [an advanced search here](http://www.devmaster.net/engines/search.php).

Answer (score 0):

[SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) has some nice 2D drawing primitives. It uses OpenGL for acceleration by default; if that's a problem, a lower-level library like [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/) is very good.

Other than those, off the top of my head, I can only think of [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/), which has support for these kinds of things as well.